# How do I set the user agent for Ruby's RestClient?

Tags: ruby, user-agent, rest-client

I'm interested in setting my own user agent when using the ruby RestClient gem.

[http://github.com/archiloque/rest-client](http://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

However, I can't find any documentation on how to do so. Any pointers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
RestClient.get 'http://localhost', :user_agent => "myagent"
```

See https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient.rb

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the accepted answer is very clear. User agent is set just by a header of the request. And what I see in [sources](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/request.rb) is that they set default user agent by setting `:user_agent` header to the request. It depends on the way you use the API how you set it. See `#default_headers` method in the linked source file.